# Check is value inserted when update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to check is same value inserted in this field when I update a field.

ex: this is my table

```
id     region      region_manager_id
1      test1       rm1
2      test2       rm7
3      test3       rm9
4      test4       rm8
5      test5       rm3
```

Now if want to update region_manager_id = rm1 Where id = 3 this should not be because **rm1** already assigned for id=1. 
so how to check same value is already inserted for another row when I update a field. is it possible in a single query?.

Comment: Are you looking for the UNIQUE index? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: you can add an unique constraint

Comment: Check this in the mysql manual, it contains all you are looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: you can also take a look at the REPLACE command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unique Key on region_manager_id , You can check duplicate id by error code. When mysql error code 1062 it means duplicate entry.

```
if(mysqli_errno($Conn)==1062){
   error =  "duplicate entry error message";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your place, I would try two aprroaches, first with PHP and second directly on your database.

1st: in your PHP code, you can try to fetch a query like this: "SELECT id FROM table WHERE region_manager_id = 'rm1';", and if this query will return with NULL, then your region_manager_id is not used already in other row of your table.

2nd: you can use [foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) and [unique key statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp), with this solution, your database will raise an error if you try to alter your table with already existing region_magnager_id key.

I hope this will help. :-)